# Forward declaration in ANN Library

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, kdtree

I'm using the ANN Library (https://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/). There is a function

```
ANNkdTree::getStats(ANNkdStats &st)
```

which provides the kdtree statistics. The library's manual defines this function like this:

```
class ANNkdStats { // stats on kd-tree
public:
   int dim; // dimension of space
   int n_pts; // number of points
   [...]
}
```

However, if I follow the function calls, I can only find a forward declaration

```
class ANNkdStats;
```

The only thing that I want to do is a simple use of this function

```
ANNkdStats st;
kdTree->getStats(st);
```

And the compiler output follows:

```
37: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class ANNkdStats’
     ANNkdStats *st = new ANNkdStats();

include/ANN/ANN.h:701:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class ANNkdStats’
 class ANNkdStats;    // stats on kd-tree
```

I'm not used to work with forward declaration methods, and I don't know how to solve it, because I can't modify the library.

Thanks in advance for your answers. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ANNkdStats` class is defined inside the `ANN/ANNperf.h` header file:

```
class ANNkdStats {          // stats on kd-tree
public:
    int     dim;            // dimension of space
    int     n_pts;          // no. of points

    // ...

    ANNkdStats()            // basic constructor
    { reset(); }

    void merge(const ANNkdStats &st);   // merge stats from child 
};
```

Adding a

```
#include "ANN/ANNperf.h"
```

directive should be enough (`ANNperf.h` includes in turn `ANN.h`).

This assumes that the ANN include directory is already on the compiler's search path (`g++ -Iinclude_dir`).